# How to disable the particular toolbar icon in MFC

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, mfc

I Have the toolbar.Inside that around 8 toolbar icons are present.In that I have to Disable 5 toolbar icons out of 8.
I know the command `ON_UPDATE_COMMAND_UI(ID_ABC,Fun1)`
here

```
OnUpdateFun1(CCmdUI* pCmdUI)
{
  pCmdUI->Enable(FALSE);
}
```

But I don't want to use this function,I am looking for any other alternative... Is there to achieve this?
And also how to hide the icons.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Why do you want another method? Explain it.

Comment: *"I don't want to use this function"* (which is a macro, really) - Without a convincing explanation, why you cannot use the canonical solution to your problem, your question ceases to be useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use command handler for a range of IDs to enable/disable group of buttons:

```
ON_UPDATE_COMMAND_UI_RANGE(id1, id2, memberFxn)
```